# meaning of gaze upon

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of 'gaze upon'?

Below is the full sentence.

But gaze upon things which although absent are securely present to the mind.

Comment: It means use your "mind's eye" to see them.

Comment: Have you tried consulting a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

"Gaze upon" most literally means "look at"

The particular example you have provided involves some flowery language. It could be rewritten in a simpler way (which sounds much worse):

"But look at things that are not here but are in present in thought"